# Limit points of $\left\{ \frac{m}{2^{n}} \right\}$ where $m,n$ are natural numbers.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E = \left\{\frac{m}{2^{n}}\right\}$ where $m,n$ are integers, then $0$ is the only limit point of this set.

$($true$/$false$) ?$

I think the $0$ is the only limit point of this set. Since, as $n \to \infty$ terms of this sequence come nearer to $0$.

But the statement is false according to answer key.

Comment: The set ranges over all $n$ and $m$ so even if you take $n$ large you can compensate by taking $m$ even larger. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational

Comment: Given a real number $x$ consider the sequence $a_k = \frac{[x2^k]}{2^k}$ (i.e. $m = [x2^k]$ and $n = 2^k$ where $[\cdot]$ is the closest integer function).

Comment: You may also want to consider my [recent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038340/subsequential-lims-of-x-n-1-1-over2-2-over2-3-over2-1-over4-4-over4) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3034340/find-the-subsequential-limits-for-x-n-left-1-1-over-10-2-over-10-cdo) since they are similar to yours

Comment: It is not too difficult to show that the set is dense in $[0,1]$, similar to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2247683/real-numbers-of-the-form-fracm10n-with-m-n-in-mathbbz-and-n-ge/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your set contains $$\frac34,\frac78,\frac{15}{16},\ldots\to 1$$so $1$ is a limit point.

Comment: Oh, yeah. If i take $m = 2^{n}-1$ then i will have this sequence converging to $1$. In general, this set has countably infinite limit points. Right$?$

Comment: @Mathsaddict this set is dense in $\mathbb R$ (i,e every point is a limit point)

Comment: @Anvit then this set has uncountable limit points!

Comment: @Mathsaddict, Yep, thats correct. Check the link in second comment on your post.

Answer (score 1):

It is not too difficult to show that the set is dense, similar to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2247683/real-numbers-of-the-form-fracm10n-with-m-n-in-mathbbz-and-n-ge/).

We can generalise the problem ...

---

> **Propositions 1**. $\forall r \in [0,\infty)$ and $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists m,n \in \mathbb{N}: \left|r-\frac{m}{q^n}\right|<\varepsilon$, for a fixed $q\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0,1\}$.

[From](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)
$$\color{red}{0\leq m}=\left \lfloor r\cdot q^n \right \rfloor \leq r\cdot q^n < \left \lfloor r\cdot q^n \right \rfloor +1=m+1 \Rightarrow 
\frac{m}{q^n} \leq r < \frac{m}{q^n}+\frac{1}{q^n}$$
we have
$$\left|r-\frac{m}{q^n}\right|<\frac{1}{q^n}$$
By "adjusting" $n>0$ we can find one such that $\frac{1}{q^n} < \varepsilon$. Also, $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$.

*NOTE:* This means that $M_q=\left\{\frac{m}{q^n} \mid m,n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$, $q\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0,1\}$, is dense in $[0,\infty)$ or any point in $[0,\infty)$ is a limit point for $M_q$.

---

> **Proposition 2** $\left\{\left\{\frac{m}{q^n}\right\} \mid m,n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$, for a fixed $q\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0,1\}$, is dense in $[0,1]$.
>
> (the second $\{\}$ is the [fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part)).

For $\forall r \in [0,1)$ and $\forall \varepsilon >0$ s.t. $0\leq r < r+ \varepsilon < 1$, we always have (from **proposition 1**) $m,n \in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. 
$$\color{red}{0}\leq r \leq \color{red}{\frac{m}{q^n}} < r+ \varepsilon < \color{red}{1}$$
(because if $M_q$ is dense in $[0,\infty)$, then it is also dense in $[0,1) \subset [0,\infty)$. But this means (see the parts highlighted in red) that $\frac{m}{q^n} = \left\{\frac{m}{q^n}\right\}$ ($\{\}$ is the [fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part)). The only point left to check is $\{1\}$. For this purpose, we will be looking at 
$$r_k=1-\frac{1}{k} < 1-\frac{1}{k} + \varepsilon < 1$$
And again, (from **proposition 1**) we have $m_k,n_k \in\mathbb{N}$ s.t.
$$r_k=1-\frac{1}{k} \leq \frac{m_k}{q_k^n} < 1-\frac{1}{k} + \varepsilon < 1$$
or
$$\left|1-\frac{m_k}{q_k^n}\right|\leq \left|1-r_k\right|=\frac{1}{k}$$
which, again, can be made as small as we want and we covered $\{1\}$ too and thus the entire $[0,1] = [0,1) \cup \{1\}$

---

Summarising all these and making $q=2$ the answer is obviously **false**.