# Find limits point of the set $A=\left\{ \frac{m}{2^n}| m\in \mathbb{Z}, n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

find the limit points of set

> $$A=\left\{ \frac{m}{2^n}| m\in \mathbb{Z}, n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$

For given any $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$ choosing $m=1+ \alpha\  2^n$ give me $\alpha $ as a limit point.

But it seems   that in fact every rational point is limit point of this set . hence this is dense set.

But please provide some hint for proving that every rational point is limit point of this set.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: A is a group under addition

Comment: And another one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3053887/limit-points-of-left-fracm2n-right-where-m-n-are-natural-numbe/