# Limit points of $\frac{p}{2^k}$

Tags: real-analysis

Find all limit points of the set $S = \{\frac{p}{2^k} : p \in \mathbb{Z}, k \in \mathbb{N}\}$. 
I could prove that all elements of $S$ are limit points of $S$. However, answer is all real numbers. Any help?

Comment: Can you show that between any two (distinct) real numbers, there's an element of $S$?

Comment: Hint: prove that $\;S\;$ is dense in $\;\Bbb R\;$ , i.e. $\;\overline S=\Bbb R\;$, which is the same as proving that any non-empty open interval contains an element of $\;S\;$ .

Comment: You will also find a proof of density [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3053887/limit-points-of-left-fracm2n-right-where-m-n-are-natural-numbe/3053985#3053985).

Answer (score 1):

Take an arbitrary point on the reals, and write it in binary notation.  For example, x = 101.111100001010...Then x can be approached by 101, 101.1, 101.11, 101.111, 101.1111, 101.11110, ...each of which is a fraction with denominator a power of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Given $x \in \Bbb R$, consider the sequence $$x_n := \dfrac{\lfloor 2^n x\rfloor}{2^n}.$$
Show that $\{x_n\} \subset S$ and $x_n \to x$. Conclude from this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some intuition to get you started, in order to understand why your answer is wrong and the correct answer is all real numbers.

Look at an [ordinary ruler](https://www.ginifab.com/feeds/cm_to_inch/actual_size_ruler.html) marked [in inches (using the imperial system of units)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_of_length#Imperial/US). You will see each inch divided in half, each $1/2$ inch divided in half to give fourths, each $1/4$ inch divided in half to give eighths, each $1/8$ inch divided in half to give sixteenths... In the abstract, you can continue this forever, using arbitrarily short subdivision lengths $1/2^n$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$ (although I don't think I've ever seen an actual physical ruler go any shorter than $1/2^5$, and even that is rare).

Perhaps from this it will become evident to you that inside the 1 inch long interval from inch mark number $N$ to inch mark number $N+1$, the subdivision points are dense, and every real number in that interval is a limit point of the set of subdivision points. And then, letting $N$ vary over $\mathbb Z$, you can see that the set of subdivision points over the entire real line is dense.

Once you understand this picture, turning it into a mathematical proof is not actually very hard. The key is to notice that for each $r > 0$, if you choose a natural number $n$ so large that $2^n > \frac{1}{r}$, then $\frac{1}{2^n} < r$. Each real number $x$ is contained in one of the subdivision intervals $\left[\frac{k}{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n}\right]$ (i.e. the union of those intervals is the entire real line), and therefore $x$ has distance less than $r$ from either of the two subdivision points at the ends of that interval.